# asp.net mvc dynamic/relative routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm developing a website which has a modular structure.
Every segment of the url presents an content item.
For example url: www.mysite.com/blogs/programming/2010/01/

Root item is 'blogs' of type 'area'. It has a child item 'programming' of type 'blog'.

Now there's '2010/01' left of the url.
Last valid (routable) item 'programming' was a blog so I need to map '2010/01' to action

BlogController.Date(int blogid, int year, int? month, int? day)

Every controller comes from a module (separate dll), which registers some item types (blog registers types 'blog' (routable) and 'post' (not routable). 'blog' can have children of type 'post').
When last valid (routable) item of the url is detected, logic knows which assembly and controller to look for. Now I need a way to invoke correct action with correct parameters.

Some routes for item of type 'blog'

```
{year}/
{year}/{month}
{year}/{month}/{day}
feed/
category/{category-name}/
tag/{tag-name}/
search/{*phrase}
{*post-name}
```

Any suggestions what would be a simple way to do the routing?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the action parameter signature problem, I personally would create a new Model class "BlogModel" and have only that as your single parameter. This way, you'd have a consistent action parameter signature. However, this would require a bit more work, as you would need to create a custom ModelBinder object "BlogModelBinder" and register it to the ModelBinderFactory (or in MVC3 the DependencyResolver). In the "BlogModelBinder" you simply look up the RouteData's parameters and values and bind it to the corresponding field in your "BlogModel."

From my personal experience, I don't think there's an easy way to register your routes: you still would have to individually register the route urls to a specific action. Unless someone has an efficient way of registering the route urls, you can take solace in knowing that we all have to get our hands dirty with the plumbing code.